# Sorting variables in Eclipse by Type

Tags: eclipse, sorting, variables

I use the Eclipse IDE, I have spent a bit of time searching online and in the IDE itself, I can't figure out how to sort variables by type.

I have looked into the formatter, save options, Java > appearance > members sort order, and I have looked online.
There is a good chance I missed the solution to my problem but I figured I would ask while I search.

My goal is when I save/clean
this:

```
String d;
SomeClassFromImportedPackage a;
int b;
String c;
SomeClassFromImportedPackage e;
String f;
```

becomes:

```
int b;
String d;
String c;
String f;
SomeClassFromImportedPackage a;
SomeClassFromImportedPackage e;
```

the order of String, int, SomeClass... doesn't matter as of now, it would be cool if somehow the sort also did alphabetical with it
like this:

```
SomeClassFromImportedPackage a;
SomeClassFromImportedPackage e;
int b;
String c;
String d;
String f;
```